# SQL query to show data by today(current) date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get the record from database with current date only here is the query I have tried bu getting no records from table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
WHERE transaction_date = GETDATE();
```

Comment: it compares not just date but timepart as well. I dont think u ll have exact transaction on date+time . try comparing just date part not date and time

Comment: Then how should I modify this query Sir can you please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare the date part

```
   Select *from Transactions
        WHERE 
    CONVERT(char(10), transaction_date  ,126)=CONVERT(char(10), getdate(),126);
```

Comment: It would be *even better* to convert the `DATETIME` into a `DATE` instead of converting to a **string** ..... always use the **most appropriate** datatype - don't just always convert everything to a string because it's easy and works.....

Answer (score 5):

It's the current date, so the records with future dates don't exist. You just need to get all transactions greater than `00:00:00` of today.

```
SELECT * FROM `Transactions` WHERE transaction_date >= CURRENT_DATE+" 00:00:00";
```

Answer (score 2):

store the date in a variable and CONCAT it in the query

see below:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
query = "select * from table where Date = " + currentDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove/reset time to 00:00, this will allow to make comparisons for today.

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

You can define variables with today's date start and end like this:

```
declare @TodayStart datetime = getdate()
declare @TodayEnd datetime = getdate()

set @TodayStart = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) -- example: 2017-08-20 00:00:00.000
set @TodayEnd = DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(dd, 1, @TodayStart)) -- example: 2017-08-20 23:59:59.000
```

So your query to get all transactions within today date range will become:

```
Select *from Transactions
    WHERE transaction_date  between @TodayStart AND @TodayEnd
```